# Event listeners in select field material-ui

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm new to react and material - ui. I want to create  2 select fields button which depend on each other.

The first field contains 2 options: "vegetable" and "meat".
The second field contains "carrot", "spinach", "tomato","chicken", "beef", and "pork".

I want the select fields to work like this:
When I choose "vegetable" in the first field, the second field will be selectable only to "carrot", "spinach", "tomato".

When I choose "meat" in the first field the second field will be selectable only to "chicken", "beef", "pork".

Any example program would be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Hi Dan thank you for leaving comment. I have posted the code example

Answer (score 0):

I found it how to do it with javascript. However, I'd like to do it in typescript as my project requires to do so. Does anybody know how to convert these codes into typescript?

```
    Form = React.createClass({

// render :: a -> ReactElement
render: function(){
    self = this;
    models = !!this.state.make ? this.state.models[this.state.make.label] : [];
    return <div>

        <SimpleSelect
            placeholder = "Select a make"
            options = {this.state.makes.map(function(make){
                return {label:make, value: make};
            })}
            value = {this.state.make}

            // onValueChange :: Item -> ()
            onValueChange = {function(make) {
                self.setState ({make: make, model: undefined}, function(){
                    self.refs.models.focus();
                });
            }}

            // onFocus :: Item -> String -> ()
            onFocus = {function(item, reason){
                self.setState({focused: true});
            }}

            // onBlur :: Item -> String -> ()
            onBlur = {function(item, reason){
                self.setState({focused: false});
            }}

            // onEnter :: Item -> ()
            onEnter = {function(item){
                if (typeof item == "undefined")
                    alert("you did not select any item");
            }}

            style = {this.state.focused ? {color: "#0099ff"} : {}}/>

        <SimpleSelect
            ref = "models"
            placeholder = "Select a model"
            options = {models.map(function(model){
                return {label: model, value: model};
            })}
            value = {this.state.model}

            // disabled :: Boolean
            disabled = {typeof this.state.make == "undefined"}

            onValueChange = {function(model) {
                self.setState({model: model});
            }}
            style = {{
                marginTop: 20,
                opacity: !!this.state.make ? 1 : 0.5
            }}/>

    </div>
},

// getInitialState :: a -> UIState
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        focused: false,
        make: undefined,
        makes: ["Bentley", "Cadillac", "Lamborghini", "Maserati", "Volkswagen"],
        model: undefined,
        models: {
            Bentley: ["Arnage", "Azure", "Continental", "Corniche", "Turbo R"],
            Cadillac: ["Allante", "Catera", "Eldorado", "Fleetwood", "Seville"],
            Lamborghini: ["Aventador", "Countach", "Diablo", "Gallardo", "Murcielago"],
            Maserati: ["Bitturbo", "Coupe", "GranTurismo", "Quattroporte", "Spyder"],
            Volkswagen: ["Beetle", "Fox", "Jetta", "Passat", "Rabbit"]
        }
    }
}
```